make_clickable and parenthesis breaks the URL
The make_clickable function will convert a text URL into a clickable HREF. This works well, even with text URLs that contain a space.
But consider this URL when typed into a post or comment box:
 https://www.example.com/some-page(2).jpg 

That URL will 'break' (when converted to an HREF by make_clickable) because of the closing parenthesis character just before the 'dot', turning the clickable part of the URL into
https://www.example.com/some-page(2

with the '.jpg' shown as text.
Is this fixable? (and 'duplicateable')?  (Tested with WP 6.6.1 on PHP 8.1.28 )

It's duplicatable -- I can make it happen on my local installation of WordPress. It almost seems like something that might be a good Trac ticket for WordPress Core.

Thanks for verifying. I've created a Trac ticket https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/62037 (First one, so hopeful that I did it correctly.)
